# Terminal output dropped character in interactive prompt?

Tags: bash, clojure, leiningen, tmux

I just typed a declaration for "indexed-row" that got interpreted as "indexxed-row" (with the extra x).

I'm running tmux on bash, on Ubuntu 12.04. This is Clojure 1.3 and the Leinegan REPL.

Where along the pipeline did it go wrong?

```
(user=> (def indexed-row row)
#'user/indexxed-row

user=> indexed-row
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: indexed-row in   this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0:0)
```

This is just so strange that I had to double-take to see it.